# Is averaged pairwise correlation the first principle to construct MCCA indices? -- Python cca-zoo

Tags: python

I have 3 data views and each have more than 10 variables. I use the MCCA function from the Python package, cca-zoo.

I check the averaged pairwise correlation and explained covariance of constructed indices. The 2rd pair of indices has the largest explained covariance, and the 3rd pair of indices has the largest averaged pairwise correlation.

I'm wondering, in principle, CCA should construct the largest averaged pairwise correlation and explained covariance through the 1st pair. Do you know why it is not the case?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.